# How to add a logger in mapstruct without having Sonar yelling at me?

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube, mapstruct

In a mapper interface , I have created a default method to map a string to an enum using a bunch of switch/case.

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN, componentModel="spring", nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface ContractMapper {

Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ContractMapper.class);

all the mappingstuff...

@Named("getEnum")
default statusEnum getStatusEnum(String status){

    if (status == null){
        return statusEnum.NoStatus;
    } else {

        switch (status) {
        case ...

        default:
            LOGGER.warn("unknown  status {}", status);
            return statusEnum.NoStatus;


        }
    }
```

I need a logger for when the mapping fail, is there a way to have one without sonar yelling at me because it is not private?

Comment: Or see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720845/logging-from-default-interface-methods

Comment: I tried it, sonar doesn't like it either

Answer (score 2):

You can always suppress the particular sonar rule for your mapper.
If you can't do that then you could use an `abstract` class instead of an interface.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN, componentModel="spring", nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public abstract class ContractMapper {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ContractMapper.class);

//...
}
```